# probability space: Prove that $\mu(\cap_{i=1}^nA_i) > 0$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a probability space (i.e., $\mu(X) = 1)$. be
$A_1, A_2, \ldots , A_n \in A$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i) > n−1$. Prove that $\mu(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i) > 0$.

I tried to use the formula in the general case which is this one:

$\mu(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cap \ldots \cup A_n) = 
\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)+\mu(A_3)+\ldots+\mu(A_n)
-\mu(A_1 \cap A_2)-\mu(A_1 \cap A_3)-\ldots-\mu(A_{n-1} \cap A_n)
+\mu(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)+\mu(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4)+\ldots+\mu(A_{n-2} \cap A_{n-1} \cap A_n)
-\ldots 
+\ldots
(\ast)\mu(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap \ldots \cap A_n)$

Observation:
$(\ast)$ is $-$ if $n$ is even.

$(\ast)$ is $+$ if $n$ is odd.

I realized that using the formula I can't kill the problem, because these terms with signs alternating in the middle $-\mu(A_1 \cap A_2)-\mu(A_1 \cap A_3)-\ldots-\mu(A_{n-1} \cap A_n)
+\mu(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)+\mu(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4)+\ldots+\mu(A_{n-2} \cap A_{n-1} \cap A_n)
-\ldots 
+\ldots$ makes it difficult. For the $n=2$ case, it's OK to use this formula...for the general case, I couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i^c) < 1$$
($c$ denoting complement)